# Android: not getting xml out of http get request with basic authentication

Tags: java, android, authorization, httprequest

My goal is to get the xml from an [API](http://www.ns.nl/en/travel-information/ns-api/documentation-travel-recommendations.html). The API uri I use, including parameters is  http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-treinplanner?fromStation=Roosendaal&toStation=Eindhoven. I am given a username and password, for what I think probably is basic authorization.

I tried various things like something with an Authenticator, the format http://username:password@webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-treinplanner, but at the end of a lot of SO searching I ended up with something with a `setRequestProperty` with the basic authorization.

I put the code into an AsyncTask which seems to work correctly so I will just put the code from inside `doInBackground` in here.

As the java `FileNotFoundException` I first got didn't give me much information, I found out how to use the `getErrorStream` to find out more.

```
            InputStream in;
            int resCode;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-treinplanner?fromStation=Roosendaal&toStation=Eindhoven");

                String userCredentials = "username:password";
                String encoding = new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                try {
                    resCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        Log.i("rescode","ok");
                        in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    } else {
                        Log.i("rescode","not ok");
                        in = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                    }
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
```

Then, in `onPostExecute` I print the response, but the response I get is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<soap:Header></soap:Header>
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>006:No customer found for the specified username and password</faultstring></soap:Fault>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This is of course not right, it should give a full xml of in this case a train voyage recommendation.

I tested with my browsers, and also using a HTTP request tool called Postman which returned the correct xml so all the uri's, parameters, username and password are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding used is wrong. The base64 encoding used randomly returns whitespaces in the middle, adding `encoding = encoding.replaceAll("\\s+","");` actually fixed it.